# why when run my code the function doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, function

I made a function to get the larger number out of two when I run it it prints  a random large number

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int larger(int num1,int num2);
int main()
{
  int n1,n2,result;
  result=larger(n1,n2);
  cout<<"enter two number\n";
  cin>>n1>>n2;
  cout<<"the larger number is "<<result<<endl;
}
int larger(int num1,int num2)
{
   int max;
   if (num1>=num2)
   max=num1;
   else
   max=num2;
   return max;
}
```

Comment: you have to compute the results *after* you get the input.

Comment: C++ is not a spreadsheet. `result=larger(n1,n2);` makes this calculation. The End. If `n1` and `n2` is later updated, like being typed in, this does not automatically recalculate the `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are calling the function before inputting 'n1' and 'n2'.
`result=larger(n1, n2)`
should come after the `cin >>...`